# AWS CLI / jq - transforming JSON with tags, and showing information even for non-defined tags

Tags: json, jq, aws-cli

I'm facing an issue when trying to process output of 'aws ec2 describe-instances' command with 'jq', and I really need some help.

I want to transform JSON output into CSV file with the list of all instances, with
columns 'Name,InstanceId,Tag-Client,Tag-CostCenter'.

I've been using jq's select with a command like:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances |
  jq -r '.Reservations[].Instances[]
    | (.Tags[]|select(.Key=="Name")|.Value) + "," + .InstanceId + "," 
      + (.Tags[]|select(.Key=="Client")|.Value) + ","
      + (.Tags[]|select(.Key=="CostCenter")|.Value)'
```

However using selects in this way, only those entries containing all the tags are displayed, not showing those that contain one of the tags only.

I understand the behavior, which is similar to a grep, but I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to perform this operation using jq, so in the case that one tag is not defined, would just return string "" and not remove the whole line.

I've found a reference about using 'if' clauses in jq ([https://ilya-sher.org/2016/05/11/most-jq-you-will-ever-need/], but wondering in anyone has resolved such case without having to make this logic or splitting the command in different executions.

Comment: It looks like you could use something like ‘(select(...)|.Value) // ""’. Please follow the mcve guidelines as much as possible so a more definitive answer can be given: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever you are given an array of key/value pairs (the tags here) and you want to extract values by their key, it'll be easier to map them into an object so you can access them directly. Functions like `from_entries` will work well with this.

However, since you're also trying to retrieve values not within this tag array, you can approach it a little differently to save some steps. Using `reduce` or `foreach`, you can go through each of the tags and add it to an object that holds all the values you're interested in. Then you can map the values you want into an array then convert to a csv row.

So if your goal is to create rows of `Tags[Name], InstaceId, Tags[Client], Tags[CostCenter]` for each instance, you could do this:

```
# for each instance
.Reservations[].Instances[]
# map each instance to an object where we can easily extract the values
  | reduce .Tags[] as $t (
        { InstanceId }; # we want the InstanceId from the instance
        .[$t.Key] = $t.Value # add the values to the object
    )
# map the desired values to an array
  | [ .Name, .InstanceId, .Client, .CostCenter ]
# convert to csv
  | @csv
```

And the good news is, if `Name`, `Client`, or `CostCenter` doesn't exist in the tag array, or even `InstanceId`, then they'll just be `null` which becomes empty when converted to csv.